# Visual studio 2022 convert project from .net to .net(framework)

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, reportviewer

I want to convert my project in visual studio 2022 from .net to .net (framework), as there are two options for creating windows form application one that supports .net 6 & 7 and some core also.
But i want to run crystal reports in that app & i am not able to add crystal reports viewer as it says on website that it only supports .net 4 versions.

I created a new project in .net (framework ) and it worked i was able to add report viewer and all.
But i have already worked a lot on this project and i dont want to create it again.
Is there any solution to migrate it to that option.
I have tried many things, like editing the project file and adding net481 in the framework but it also didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

Crystal for VS does not support .NET Core and probably never will.
It has strong dependencies on COM components, which are not supported in .NET core.

One option is to keep the Crystal portion of your app in .NET 4.8 and call that app from your .NET core app.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the OP wants to convert his project to .NET 4.8, not the other way round.